# Win Toolset Webview2 installation

Tags: webview2, wix4

I have the following in my WIX 4 project.This snippet supposed to check if WebView2 is installed on the target machine, and if not, install it.

```
  <Property Id="WVRTINSTALLED">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="EBWebView" Type="raw" Bitness="default" />
  </Property>

  <!-- [Download Bootstrapper] Use fwlink to download bootstrapper to user TEMP folder then invoke it-->
  <CustomAction  Id="DownloadAndInvokeBootstrapper" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden Invoke-WebRequest -Uri &quot;https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=2124703&quot; -OutFile &quot;$env:TEMP\MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe&quot; ; &amp; $env:TEMP\MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe /install" Return="check" />

  <!-- Config execute sequence of custom action -->
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- [Download Bootstrapper] Use fwlink to download the bootstrapper to user TEMP folder and invoke-->
    <!-- Only run DownloadAndInvokeBootstrapper action during app install, app repair and when WVRT wasn't installed-->
    <Custom Action="DownloadAndInvokeBootstrapper" Before="InstallFinalize" Condition="NOT(REMOVE OR WVRTINSTALLED)" />
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem is, the installation of WebView2 is allways happening, even if it is allready installed in the target machine...

That am I doing wrong?